# VBA - make hyperlink display text equal to active cell contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

How do I make the display text for this hyperlink equal to the contents of the active cell, cell B50, rather than the text "B50"?

The rest of the formula works, it's just the display text I need to edit.

```
Range("B50").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""[wbk]strLastSheetName!C13"",""B50"")"
```

Edit:
Now the display text is working, but the hyperlink isn't working. I'm trying to have the hyperlink to go to cell C13 of the last sheet in the workbook. I have:

```
Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbk = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbk.Worksheets(wbk.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function
```

Then within the Sub:

```
Dim strLastSheetName As String
strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()

Range("B50").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK([" & wbk " "]strLastSheetName!C13," & Range("B50").Value & ")"
```

Comment: `Range("B50").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK([wbk]strLastSheetName!C13," & Range("B50").value & ")"` maybe?

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the display text value!
But now it isn't returning a hyperlink. Can you tell if there's an issue with the other part of the formula that references the last sheet of the workbook? I'm trying to have the hyperlink to go to cell C13 of the last sheet in the workbook.

I have:
`Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbk = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbk.Worksheets(wbk.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function`

Then within the Sub:
`Dim strLastSheetName As String
strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()`

Comment: I would be better to edit your question, multiple lines of code are difficult to parse, That said, if `wbk` is a variable in your code, you would use something like: `Range("B50").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK([" & wbk & "]strLastSheetName!C13," & Range("B50").value & ")"`

Comment: If `strLastSheetName` is another variable, you need to also concatenate it: `Range("B50").FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK([" & wbk & "]" & strLastSheetName & "!C13," & Range("B50").value & ")"`

Comment: Noted, I have edited my question. I tried your most recent suggestion and I got error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out--this works:

```
    Range("B" & Lastrow).Select
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "" & strLastSheetName & "!C13"
```